# Mongo Collection Java- Update using Object

Tags: mongodb, validation, crud, quarkus

I am writing a CRUD app using Quarkus and Mongo, and thus am using a `MongoCollection` to implement this.

I am utilizing Hibernate Validators for validation to ensure my data is as it should be.

The issue I am running into is that the `MongoCollection` only provides updates using Bson (`collection.updateOne(Bson search, Bson update)`), and not for the entire object. This would be fine but keeps me from being able to properly use validators to ensure proper data integrity.

Until I hit this block, my idea for updating was to:

- ingest generic json, in the form of `ObjectNode` and the object's id
- get the object to update
- Use Jackson's built-in updating features to apply the updates to the object from the given `ObjectNode`
- Validate the resulting state
- save the object to Mongo

However, this doesn't work when I can't update the whole object at once. Am I attacking this from the right angle? I've found a lot on how to do updates, but not a lot related to validation. I also see that I can specify on the Mongo side validation rules, but as I am fairly 'hands off' when using Mongo in this way, so needing to apply special Bson validation isn't ideal.

<strike>Is it possible for me to just re-insert the updated object to Mongo using `collection.insertOne(object)`? this assumes that the object would have the same `_id` as the original. Would this update the object as intended, or are there side effects?</strike>

Edit:: no, it is not. Mongo throws an error for duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, what I wanted was `collection.findOneAndReplace()`